# tensorflow reshaping convolutional filters for visualization

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I have a 4D tensor of filter/kernel weights (of convolutional layer).
They're being passed to the subsequent operation with shape [5,5,3,32], 32 RGB 5x5 filters.

to collect their values for monitoring/analysis/storage using tf.summary.image I need to reshape this tensor into the shape [32,5,5,3], to then view/store each of the 32 filters as individual images of [5,5,3] 
is this possible purely using `tf.reshape()`? or do I need to do multiple tensor transformations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `transpose` instead of `reshape`, `tf.transpose(t, (3,0,1,2))` should do what you need (suppose `t` is your tensor here), which shifts the last axis as the first axis.

Comment: I had a feeling a transpose would do the job. thank you :)